# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data - but data is correct

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

### Solution:

I had simply forgotten that I had a hidden input element with a max file size, which was also hit by

```
$(this).closest(".reginput").find("input").trigger("change");
```

To prevent it from being handled by my validation script, which won't know what to do with it and return the empty string which caused this error, I added

```
.not("[type='hidden']")
```

to exclude it.
Now it works like it should. Thanks a bunch to Jared Farrish for bumping heads with me. :)

### Original Question

I have a registration form which guides new users through one input at a time, and one of the inputs is of type="file".

With jQuery, I check whether each input is a file when the user inputs something, to decide how to validate it. The value I need validated is sent as a JSON-formatted string to a PHP-script, using $.post() and .done().

The file is an optional profile picture, and if the user selects a file for upload, I use the file API to check it's size and mime-type, which is sent as a JSON object to the server.

On the first try everything goes well, the server returns a JSON formatted string with a custom response code, which is sent through JSON.parse().

I have also added a button next to all inputs which triggers the change event when it is clicked. This is a fall back for users who need visual input on how to "send" the input value. However, if I try pressing this once the picture has already been validated, I get the error

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data

I have checked the returned value from my AJAX call, and it is correct:

> {"response":"OK","name":"picture"}

I don't understand why this wouldn't be parsed properly, but maybe it has something to do with the change event being triggered by a different element?

Here is the related code:

### Triggering change event with button

```
$(".sendinput").click(function(){
    if($(this).closest(".reginput").find("input").length == 0){ //if an input can't be found, operate with a select
        $(this).closest(".reginput").find("select").trigger("change");
    } else if ($(this).closest(".reginput").find("select").length == 0){ //if a select can't be found, operate with an input
        $(this).closest(".reginput").find("input").trigger("change");
    }
```

### Reacting to change event

```
if($(this).attr("type") !== "file"){

    //Stuff to do if the input is NOT a file

} else {
    $.post("checkinput.php",{"code":{"name":$(this).attr("name"),"size":e.target.files[0].size,"type":e.target.files[0].type}}).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    var datax = $.parseJSON(data);
    regCheckHandler(datax);
    });
    };
});
```

### Show preview of profile picture

```
$("input[type=file]").change(function(event){
var prev = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
console.log(prev);
$("#pictureprev").css("background-image","url(" + prev + ")");
});
```

**Sorry for the messy code! I've been rushing it a bit.**

### Edit:

**The returned value is parsed correctly if I try switching image files, which triggers the change event natively. So I suppose the problem must lie with the trigger()ed event, although I still can't understand why!**

Comment: The error message means that you are trying to parse an empty string; the equivalent of `$.parseJSON('')`.

Comment: The string isn't empty though. console.log(data) gives me -> {"response":"OK","name":"picture"}

Comment: The only way to get that error message is to parse an empty string, so either you are showing the wrong error message or the wrong data.

Comment: That makes no sense though. :/
How can "data" pass a completely valid string to console, and then be empty when it's parsed? Still, it's only when I trigger the "change" event with .trigger(). Edit: Also, thanks for replying! :)

Comment: I assume it's the `else if` part of the click handler; since this is seemingly a "wizard-style" procedure, are you hiding other elements that are still in the DOM and in `.reginput`? In other words, you're triggering the wrong element perhaps? Your secondary selector is pretty generic (`"input"`).

Comment: @JaredFarrish Good call! But there is only one "input" or "select" element within each ".reginput", so that shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: If you're stating the problem only arises when using that click handler, I'd start debugging there.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I'll give it a try. Maybe it has something to do with event bubbling? Still don't know how it can relate to "data" being empty and not empty at the same time - but here's to blind debugging! :)

Comment: Do you have a page to see it in action? We need a working demonstration, as I feel like you may be leaving something out without realizing it (because you're focused on the wrong thing).

Comment: The page is in Norwegian though, so it might not be helpful - but feel free to have a look: https://mariko-chan.com/register.php
You're probably right - it is usually what I don't think of checking that is the problem with these errors. :)

Comment: The password needs to be at least six characters long, and must contain one upper case character and one non-word character (abcDe* should pass) :)

Comment: Ooooh, @JaredFarrish I'm a moron! You were completely right, because I do actually have another input, to regulate file size client side! That is probably where the problem lies. Because the max_file_size input won't be handled correctly at all when passed through my validation system. Silly me.

Comment: Remember that `console.log(data)` will not log an empty value, so it's probable you didn't see the "empty" response in the first call because it was, in fact, empty. This is why I usually try to remember to add a string to debugging calls, like `console.log('checkInput response:', data);`. This way you don't end up with a false sense of security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looking at the actual code working, you do in fact have two inputs:

```
<div class="reginput">
  <span>Profilbilde</span>
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
  <input tabindex="-1" title="Profilbilde er frivillig. Kun jpg/jpeg, gif eller png er tillatt" name="picture" type="file">
  <div class="sendinput"></div>
  <img src="/template/check.svg" height="30px"><br>
  <div class="regbuttons"><div class="backbox" id="back13">Tilbake</div><div class="responsebox" id="res13">Neste</div></div>
</div>
```

I don't know *yet* if that factors in, *but* I do notice something "odd": The order of the `console.log(data)` and parse error is out of sync to what I expected.

So we have:

[image: out of sync]

I would expect the `JSON.parse()` syntax error to occur *after* your `console.log(data)`, since that's the order in which your code is running. This seems to indicate that, in point of fact, there is another click handler being triggered, other than the one you want.

So then I decided to have a peek at the Network tab and see what's being sent:

[image: network is unexpected]

Again, not what I expected. I expected only *one* call, but there's two! Since the parse error happens *first*, I check that first (maybe suspicious?) call:

[image: is it suspicious?]

And the response:

[image: Coup de grâce?]

Is that expected? This is in fact different from the *second*, probably intended call:

[image: looks right]

And it's response:

[image: this does too]

So you might check your `checkInput.php` page and make sure it has a default JSON error response in case the request is invalid. And also make your selector more specific, so it doesn't trigger the `input MAX_FILE_SIZE` element when it shouldn't. (I'm guessing there's a stray click handler on that element that shouldn't be there, either?)

Comment: This is exactly what I realized as well, once my thought process got around to remembering it! I changed the $(".sendinput").click() function to not include inputs of type="hidden" to exclude the MAX_FILE_SIZE input you discovered, and now it works.

Somehow, all my problems in coding come down to me having forgotten something seemingly minor and insignificant, or forgetting a semi colon or something.. Sorry for bothering you with this! And thank you a lot for helping me out! :')

Comment: I tend to stay way from generic selectors, mainly because later on if you try to make changes, you can suddenly have some odd bugs that are hard to spot. Developing around events can be fun, but it can also be maddening.